# How to convert from `cell::Ref<'_, [u8]>` into `&[u8]` or the other way around?

Tags: rust

I'm modifying a library that holds `Item`s returned by [ChunkExact](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.ChunksExact.html) slice iterator.  My iterator requires interior mutability and uses a `RefCell`. As a result of that, my iterator cannot return `Items` of type `&[u8]` but returns `Ref<'_, [u8]>` instead.  The two types seem to be equivalent for practical use.  For instance, this:

```
    for i in slice.chunks_exact(2) {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
```

works just as well as this:

```
    for my_iterator() {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
```

Full working example in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c1f75a3f03730fc9bc6d06e2dab62129).

Close as they are, I cannot convert one item into the other:

```
   = note: expected enum `Option<Ref<'_, [u8]>>`
              found enum `Option<&[u8]>`
```

I saw the experimental [cell::Ref::leak](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#method.leak) method, but seems like what I'm trying to do should not require such a scary feature...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Option::as_deref`:

```
let a: Option<Ref<'_, [u8]>> = ...;
let b: Option<&[u8]> = a.as_deref();
```

`Ref<'_, T>` implements `Deref<Target = T>` which is why `Ref<'_, [u8]>` can be used like a `&[u8]` in most contexts. However, they are still different types, which is why you get the error on assigning one to the other in an option.

You cannot go the other way around and create a `Ref<'_, T>` from a `&T` since there is no `RefCell` for it to reference.

---

This will only work in a context where the original `Option<Ref>` is kept around. You cannot use this to convert your iterator from returning `Ref<'_, [u8]>`s to returning `&[u8]`s. This is because the lifetime of the `&[u8]` is bound to the `Ref`, not the original `RefCell`.

Comment: I [reworked the example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6777b71113c68c1eb2828bb13c81dbba) to use `Option::as_deref()` as suggested, and it works perfectly.  Thanks!